# Canvas.drawColor() Producing black background

Tags: java, android, draw

I'm working on a game right now, I actually finished the basics of it last night on my laptop and now I am updating the graphics to actual graphics on my Ubuntu machine. I am using the same draw method from the original game to create a background, and a player's character. However, nothing is drawn at all, and it seems to ignore my draw method. I've tried many different things, commented out code, added new code. I've been debugging for a while.

Can anyone look and see what the problem may be? I know it is probably something simple I do not see.

Draw method:

```
public void draw(){
            if (holder.getSurface().isValid()){

                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

                canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);

                paint.setColor(Color.argb(255,249,129,0));

                playerBike.drawBike(paint, canvas);//draw player character

                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
```

Run method:

```
public void run() {
            while (playing){//playing is set to true
                long startTimeFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();

                if (!paused)
                    update();
                //if (!isAlive())
                  //  gameScreen.pause();
                draw();

                timeThisFrame = System.currentTimeMillis()-startTimeFrame;
                if (timeThisFrame >= 1)
                    fps = 1000/timeThisFrame;
            }

        }
```

Related Imports:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, was something simple. I forgot to start the game's thread.